# How to Get Max Number of Multitextured Units

Tags: c++, opengl

Lets say I have a function where I want the user to be able to select the appropriate texture in a type safe manner. So instead of using a GLenum of GL_TEXTUREX I define a method as follows.

```
void activate_enable_bind(uint32_t texture_num)  {
  const uint32_t max_textures = GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS - GL_TEXTURE0;
  const uint32_t actual_texture = (GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_num);

  if (texture_num > max_textures) {
    throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: texture::activate_enable_bind()");
  }

  glActiveTexture(actual_texture);
  glEnable(target_type);
  glBindTexture(target_type, texture_id_);
}
```

Is this guaranteed to work under all implementations based on the opengl specification, or are implementers allowed to have

```
`GL_TEXTURE0 - GL_TEXTURE(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS -1)`
```

defined in a non-contiguous manner?

I was modifying my code aswell here in what I have:

```
void activate_enable_bind(uint32_t texture_num = 0)  {
  GLint max_textures = 0;
  glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &max_textures);
  if (static_cast<GLint>(texture_num) > max_textures - 1) {
    throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: texture::activate_enable_bind()");
  }

  const uint32_t actual_texture = (GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_num);

  glActiveTexture(actual_texture);
  glEnable(target_type);
  glBindTexture(target_type, texture_id_);
}
```

Comment: That if is not correct, unless texture_num starts from 1 to n.

Comment: fence post error, unit tests would have caught that. But good eye.

Comment: If you change your title to something like "How to get max number of multitextured units" this post could be more useful to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` is not on its own a useful value, but is something that you pass to [`glGet`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) to retrieve the actual value. To account for that, you'd retrieve it like this:

```
GLint max_combined_texture_image_units;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &max_combined_texture_image_units);
// and then maybe check for errors
```

As for adding to `GL_TEXTURE0`, that is safe; §3.8 of [the OpenGL 3.2 Core specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec32.core.20091207.pdf) says this:

> **Active­Texture** generates the error `INVALID_­ENUM` if an invalid *texture* is speciﬁed. *texture* is a symbolic constant of the form `TEXTURE`*i*, indicating that texture
>   unit *i* is to be modified. The constants obey `TEXTURE`*i* `= TEXTURE0+`*i* (*i* is in the
>   range 0 to *k* − 1, where *k* is the value of `MAX_­COMBINED_­TEXTURE_­IMAGE_­UNITS`).

Answer (score 1):

Your corrected code, (`GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` is an enum):

```
void activate_enable_bind(uint32_t texture_num)  {
  int value;
  glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS_ARB,&value);

  if (texture_num+1 > value) {
    throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: texture::activate_enable_bind()");
  }

  const uint32_t actual_texture = (GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_num);

  glActiveTexture(actual_texture);
  glEnable(target_type);
  glBindTexture(target_type, texture_id_);
}
```

EDIT: Also read @icktoofay answer.

Comment: @icktoofay was faster in his answer ;)