# ios - presentRenderbuffer triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I've found that when I use textures above `GL_TEXTURE18` on ios (tested on iOS 10), `presentRenderbuffer` triggers an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Is there any reason for that? Can I not use textures up to `GL_TEXTURE31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GL_TEXTUREX` are just some defined values, defined enumerations. In your case a GPU is the one that defines the actual number of supported textures and it is your responsibility to check what are these limitations.

You can get that by using `glGet` something like:

```
GLint max_combined_texture_image_units;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &max_combined_texture_image_units);
```

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629317/how-to-get-max-number-of-multitextured-units) thread.

Do note that these defines/enumerations are here just to help you, it does not mean they are actually valid or supported. The openGL API is mostly designed by passing integer values `typedef uint32_t GLenum;` so as far as the API goes you may replace `GL_TEXTURE0` with `1200` or any other value but you do need to ensure that the value is actually valid.